# Is it possible to get more missions in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Is there a way to get Jetpack Joyride to stop giving me a ton of "rub your head", "brush past lights", and "high five scientists" missions each time you work your way up to a new badge? Is there a way to get better and more unique missions?  If so, how do I go about getting them?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do that UNLESS you modify the game's contents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would you do this? Is this simply by getting new equipment, or do you have to go into the game code, etc...?

Comment: You have to go into the game code, because Jetpack Joyride is just configured to give you missions like these. You would need to ask someone else for help editing the contents though.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep playing the game and get all the way to Barry. You get option to restart progress, when you restart you will get a lot of similar missions but also get new ones. If ran out of all missions you just have to wait for developers to update the game and download new content.